# How can an extended linearizable history G be equivalent to sequential history S?

Tags: concurrency

I am undertaking a module in Concurrent Programming where some of the new content this year covers linearizability, the Java Memory Model, and sequential consistency. Our class slides are companion slides to **The Art Of Multiprocessor Programming.**

I have been doing OK with linearizability but have become confused at this point below:
[image: The art of multiprocessor programming slides]

I understand that removing pending invocations gives a complete subhistory, however I cannot understand from this example how a subset G can be equivalent to set S which is larger than it - how is G  obtained from S here?

As far as I am aware there is not enough information to determine if there are pending invocations from the diagram on the right and I am not sure why a --> b is removed in the subset that is G - at first I thought it's because they are overlapping but A and B both have linearization points for viewing them 'as sequential objects'.

I may be over looking something simple and have just misunderstood the slides.

Comment: Is ... is that Comic Sans?

Comment: Yes - all the slides are :(

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The idea of linearizability is that the parallel events behave as if each of them happened at a single point in time, during the duration of the actual execution of the event. Given a sequence of events, if the end point of event $A$ precedes the starting point of event $B$ then in *any* linearization, the time point of $A$ must precede the time point of $B$. These are the constraints $\rightarrow_G$, which we can think of as a partial order. The events are linearizable if the constraints are extendable to a *linear* order $\rightarrow_S$ such that the *semantics* match — the outcome of the events is the same as if they were applied in the order underlying $\rightarrow_S$. Perhaps this is what was meant by *equivalence*, though as you mention, it is clearly applied to the wrong objects. What is equivalent here is the actual turn of events and the turn of events given the order $\rightarrow_S$.

Comment: Thanks for your reply, I'm still just confused on a few points:

    "if the end point of event A precedes the starting point of event B then in any linearization, the time point of A must precede the time point of B. These are the constraints →G" 

  That is not the case in this example though (as far as I understand), so I think it would be possible for either A→B OR B→A to be valid once linearization points are added due to the nature in which A and B overlap - is that correct? And it's because of that ambiguous nature that they are not included in →G, but it would still be a valid for →S?

Comment: In my answer, $A$ and $B$ were just dummy placeholders. You're right that in your example, $A$ and $B$ don't have the relation I describe.

Answer (score 1):

I'm a bit late with this question, but this would be my thoughts on the slides -

There are a lot of words within the first slide which have a different meaning in this context in comparison to other scenarios.

For instance the definitions of words are :

- **Legal** - A history $H$ is legal, if for each object $x$ the projection $H|x$ meets the sequential specification
- **Sequential History** - A sequential history $H$ follows the format of an initial request, such as $A\ q:end(3)$, followed by zero or more responses and invocations - a trailing innovation is valid in this scenario.

  Note, invocations and responses of different threads may not be interleaved for a sequential history - for instance the below history is *not* valid, as the Thread's invocations and responses are interleaved.

  $ 
          A\ q.enq(3) \\
          B\ q.enq(4) \\
          A\ q:void \\
          B\ q:void
      $
- **Equivalent** - Two histories $H$ and $G$ are equivalent if their per thread projections are equal.

With this in mind

```
A history $H$ is linerizable if, it can be extended to $G$ by
    - Appending zero or more responses to pending invocations
    - Discarding other pending invocations
```

And with our definitions in mind, we can say - loosely speaking

```
There must exist a legal, perhaps arbitrary, sequential history S,
which follows the defined ordering within our complete history G
```

For instance in your slide, the following orderings (or precedences) are defined

$
  \rightarrow_{G} = \{a \rightarrow c, b\rightarrow c \}
$

Note that, as the ordering between $a$ and $b$ is undefined, we must check both interleavings.

Therefore given these orderings, it means to prove a history to be linearizable, we simply need to find **any** legal, sequential history S, which is equivalent to G and contains our defined ordering relations.

One such legal sequential to test against may be the following, ie $a \rightarrow b$

$
  \rightarrow_{S} = \{a \rightarrow b, a\rightarrow c, b \rightarrow c \}
$

And another possible legal sequential history may be the following, ie $b \rightarrow a$

$
  \rightarrow_{S} = \{b \rightarrow a, b\rightarrow c, a \rightarrow c \}
$

So, in general it should be 'easy' to prove that a History linearizable if their method innovations do not overlap. However in this scenario both $a$ and $b$ do, so we must test out both possibilities. If either yield to be true, then our history is linearizable.

Answer (score 0):

I think the confusion comes from mixing up relations and histories.

G and S are histories.  G equivalent to S means that the events happen on each process in the same order in G as in S.  (Note though the ordering of events on different processes may differ between equivalent histories.)

-->G is the relation of events in G, and similarly -->S is the relation in S.  -->G is a partial ordering, whereas -->S is a total ordering, since S is sequential.  -->S is an extension of -->G by adding ordering between parallel events in G.

Hope it helps.